# How to enable auto close bracket inside a bracket in GEANY editor

Tags: c++, programming, text-editor, geany, visual-studio-code

I like the geany text editor very much. However, one thing that I don't like is that while I code in C/C++, the auto-close bracket option does not work inside similar types of brackets.

Here's an example:

```c
int main()
{

if()
{    // at this point the curly bracket does not auto close - how do I fix that?

}
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Geany version 1.36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just problem solved

just update geany plugins and after that go to plugin manager and there u will see an auto close plugin just click that and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences->Editor-Completion and tick the auto-close quotes and brackets options. See also https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#id113

Comment: as i said i have tick that option , it autocloses the bracket also but when i try to insert another similar bracket inside the bracket it does not autoclose  the bracket.                                                  as - {      {      }